# How to read the last 10 lines of a file and grab the required data?

Tags: php

The following function `DMMRankings()` below is used to display top 25 users with most Rank points. However, I would like to edit the function to read a text file (it will have a lot of rows, like 20.000) so its required to read always the last 10 lines not all because it will be a total mess. Example two lines from the text file:

```
1,42,16, 201,stackoverflow_user, 1, 6762160, 39799, 9817242, 6762160, 39884, 10010545,stackoverflow_usersecond, 2, 1351147, 1165, 483259, 1351147, 1115, 241630, 0 
1,46,27, 201,[stackoverflow_user | stackoverflow_userother], 1, 4078465, 286991, 1594830, 4078465, 287036, 1643156,stackoverflow_userthird, 2, 1357147, 1115, 241630, 1357147, 1065, 120815, 0
```

The structure of the lines is mostly similiar but the only difference is that 5th column can contain more usernames, so we must read always the first of it. Its like that: the script should read column 4, 5 (as you can see it should read the very first name because it can be extended with additional, see: 1st and 2nd line) and column 13. So, total of 4,5,13 columns from each last 10 lines. **So my question is how to make a script to read the latest 10 lines and specific columns from this specific text file?**

The script which must be edited:

```
    function DMMRankings()
    {
        $db = $this->database[GDB];
        $num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT TOP 25 UserName, Rank, Nation FROM USER WHERE Authority IN(1, 2) ORDER BY Rank DESC');
        if ($num_rows == -1)
        {
            $db->getError();
            return;
        }

        $n = 1;
        $content = '';
        while ($row = $db->doRead())
        {
            $data = array('rank-pos' => $n++, 'rank-name' => $row['UserName'], 'rank-nation' => $row['Nation'], 'rank-user' => number_format(intval($row['Rank'])));
            $content .= Template::Load('rankinguserdmm-' . ($n % 2 == 1 ? 2 : 1), $data);
        }

        $this->content = Template::Load('user_rankingsdmm', array('rankings' => $content));
    }
```

Comment: Your pasted code has nothing to do with reading a text file... please post code that is **relevant** to the question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will fulfil your mission:

```
# read a file into an array
$lines = file('/path/to/file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

# take the last 10 lines of the file -- i.e. the last 10 values in the array
$last_ten = array_slice($lines, -10);

#create an array for the output
$output = array();

foreach ($last_ten as $l) {
    # treat the data as comma-separated values
    $arr = explode(",", $l);
    # if col 5 has multiple values, take the first one
    if (preg_match("/\[(.+?) \|/", $arr[4], $matches)) {
        $arr[4] = $matches[1];
    }
    # store the data we want in an output array.
    $output[] = array( $arr[3], $arr[4], $arr[12] );
}
print_r($output);
```

output (I made up some data based on your lines):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  201
            [1] => stackoverflow_user_7
            [2] => stackoverflow_usersecond
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  201
            [1] => stackoverflow_user_8
            [2] => stackoverflow_userthird
        )
```

(etc.)

Comment: I will test it out right away. One last thing please, since I really struggle to do it before testing. How to read columns 5,13 only if there aren't any spaces between usernames. Let's say line on column 5 or 13 with username like: `stack overflow_user_7` to be skipped? So it will read only lines without (space)

Comment: Actually, how to include reserved words that lines with both or any of these words if exist in columns 5/13 to be ignored? Word Word1, Word2 and etc ?

Comment: You would do better to ask that as a separate question.  You need to specify input and output, and what to do about the 10 lines - should more be parsed?

Comment: Basically, I want to avoid lines with specific names if exist in column 5 or 13 or even if both exist. Can I somehow make reserved words to be ignored if exist in these columns?

Comment: Yeah. if lines are ignored to grab the rest until it collects 10 valid lines with data.